# How to get function signature from arguments?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a function `f` like this:

```cpp
void f(int x) {
   cout << "Hi I'm f" << endl;
}

auto x = f;
```

But if the function is overloaded, this does not works:

```
void f(int x) {}
void f(int x, const int y) {}

auto x = f; // Which one to use ?
```

So it's impossible. But let's assume *I know which arguments I will pass to the function*, for examples I know I want to call `f(10, 20)`. Not the types of the arguments itself, but the actual values, which could differ in constness, reference-ness (assume the word exists...), or even different types by casting. In the example `20` is `int&&` and the argument const int is bindable. I assume also that there is no edge-cases and the values can only bind to one overload, which also could not compile even by directly call anyway. Is it possible to deduce the address of the overloaded function and the signature of the function ?

Pseudo-code:

```
Input: Values of arguments
Output: Address of overloaded function `f` OR function signature type (any one can be deduced from the other though)
```

It is obviously possible to call directly, but the function does "sneak around" and is directly called and looks like to be not possibly referenced.

```
template<typename... Args>
void callMeMaybe(Args... args) {
    f(args...); // I can call f... But how to get f itself ?
    auto x = static_cast<void(Args...)>(f) // does not works because f could differ in argument bind
}
```

Comment: What do you want the signature for?  Depending on what you are doing/trying to accomplish you might not even need it.

Comment: Depending on your development environment, you might use \_\_FUNCTION\_\_ or \_\_FUNC\_\_ preprocessor, as explained here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html

Comment: I would like to use a `std::bind`-like object that will store references by references and value by value. `std::bind` store all of his arguments by value, and I would like to not use `std::ref` or `std::cref`. The note is also that the type value/reference should be deduced from the signature of `f` and not to the call of the `std::bind`-like object (here like `callMeMaybe` but it does not work)

Comment: You can use a lambda like `auto x = [](auto&&... x) -> decltype(f(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)...))
{ return f(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)...);
};` to get that kind of behavior.  You just need to specify how it captures if you need that.

Comment: Use lambdas and the problem you are trying to solve does not even exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Which function gets called depends on the reference-ness/constness of the parameters as you rightly mentioned. You will have to tell the compiler the signature explicitly and then you will be able to get the function pointer. Interestingly this also works for templates.

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename Name1, typename Name2, typename Name3>
Name3 f(Name1, Name2, Name3);

int f(int);
int f(int,int const);

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Type deduction using decltype: the args must be constexpr.
    //Remember there is no runtime-reflection support in c++ yet.
    auto s = static_cast< int (*)(decltype(78), decltype(-98) ) > (f);
    cout << s(78, -98) << endl;
    cout << typeid(s).name() << endl;

    // x and y will point to the same function
    // int (*)(int) and int (*)(const int) are equivalent overloads
    auto x = static_cast<int (*)(int)>( f );
    auto y = static_cast<int (*)(int const)>( f );

    //p and q will point to the same function
    // int (*)(int, int) and int (*)(int, const int) are equivalent overloads
    auto p = static_cast<int (*)(int, int const)>( f );
    auto q = static_cast<int (*)(int, int)>( f );

    //With templates
    auto z = static_cast<string (*)(int, char, string)>( f );
    cout << z(4,'a',"Hello!!") << endl;

    //typeid to check signatures
    cout << typeid(x).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(y).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(p).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(q).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(z).name() << endl;

    return 0;
}

int f(int arg)
{
    return arg;
}

int f(int a1, int const a2)
{
    return a2; //Return the second element
}

template<typename Name1, typename Name2, typename Name3>
Name3 f(Name1 a, Name2 b, Name3 c)
{
    return c; // Return the 3rd element
}
```